# How to accede to the variable from the nested function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to accede to the variable from the nested function in JavaScript?

```
function Foo() {                // class Foo
    this.name = 'myName';

    this.bar = function() {     // 'bar' method
        return function() {     // nested method
            return this.name;   // how to accede to that?
        }
    }
}
```

Is the variant bellow optimal :?

```
    this.bar = function() {        // 'bar' method
        var innerName = this.name; // duplicated variable :-/

        return function() {        // nested method
            return innerName;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more usual approach is to keep a reference to the entire outer object:

```
function Foo() {                // class Foo
    var _self = this;

    this.name = 'myName';

    this.bar = function() {     // 'bar' method
        return function() {     // nested method
            return _self.name;   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function Foo() {                // class Foo
    var that = this;
    this.name = 'myName';

    this.bar = function() {     // 'bar' method
        return function() {     // nested method
            return that.name;   // how to accede to that?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a ES6 capable environment, you can also [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for that:

```
function Foo() {
  this.name = 'myName';

  this.bar = () = > () => this.name;
}
```